# Getting Null in return when reading data from JSON using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, swifty-json

I am reading JSON from two places 1) from a file and 2) from url. 
this is my JSON file

```
{
"People": {

    "Person1" : {

        "Name" : "Umair",
        "Age" : "22"
    },

    "Person2" : {

        "Name" : "Rehman",
        "Age" : "28"
    },

    "Person3" : {

        "Name" : "Saqib",
        "Age" : "32"
    },

    "Person4" : {

        "Name" : "Fahad",
        "Age" : "18 "
    },

  }
}
```

and this is how I read it using SwiftyJson

```
let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonFile", ofType: "json") as String!
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil)
var myName = readableJSON["People","Person1","Name"]
print(myName)
```

in result it gives me the name no problem here. when I try to get the Json from url using same method I get the complete Json file in return but when I try to get a specific field it return null. here is my  code for that

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.randomuser.me/")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // Make sure we get an OK response
        guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
            realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print("Not a 200 response")
                return
        }

        // Read the JSON                
            let readableJSONFromWeb = JSON(data: data!, options: .MutableContainers, error: nil)
            var origin = readableJSONFromWeb["results"]
            print(origin)


    }).resume()
}
```

as per above code I get this output

```
Umair
[
 {
  "id" : {
   "name" : "SSN",
   "value" : "026-36-3780"
 },
"nat" : "US",
"cell" : "(862)-296-4803",
"phone" : "(528)-560-7652",
"login" : {
  "username" : "ticklishmouse295",
  "password" : "julie",
  "sha256" : "01234103cae3a10c5813a7c5dfd069e2533860cf2786df4dc31a501eb66b9c37",
  "sha1" : "46fa91a26c5219823b0c4a2c0fd99d390c997cd9",
  "salt" : "aU4VTMOV",
  "md5" : "be3f89edd4f22f333433d2424cbf4a95"
},
"registered" : 1144149087,
"dob" : 1170844810,
"picture" : {
  "large" : "https:\/\/randomuser.me\/api\/portraits\/women\/40.jpg",
  "thumbnail" : "https:\/\/randomuser.me\/api\/portraits\/thumb\/women\/40.jpg",
  "medium" : "https:\/\/randomuser.me\/api\/portraits\/med\/women\/40.jpg"
},
"location" : {
  "state" : "north carolina",
  "street" : "9402 mcclellan rd",
  "city" : "arvada",
  "postcode" : 93836
},
"email" : "ethel.palmer@example.com",
"gender" : "female",
"name" : {
  "title" : "mrs",
  "first" : "ethel",
  "last" : "palmer"
}
}
]
```

but when I try to get a specific field using

```
var origin = readableJSONFromWeb["results","location"]
```

I get null in return

Comment: In your remote access, where you get a NSData object containing the JSON, you accidentally _again_ read the data from the url with `NSData(contentsOfURL:url!)`. You don't need to do this -  `session.dataTaskWithURL`  already returned the `NSData` in the response.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my dumb mistake. i tried to go with data returned by session.dataTaskWithURL but issue is still there

Comment: var origin = readableJSONFromWeb["results"] var data = origin["location"]

Comment: @Sanjeet verma tried your solution but it still returns null :-(

Comment: hey, try:  var data = origin.objectAtIndex(0).valueForKey("location")
I see the data is inside [ ], so maybe that might help

Comment: Look on the JSON! First you have an array, so you need to use an index `0` after "results"!

Comment: @AkshanshThakur "value of type JSON has no member objectAtIndex"

Comment: @UmairAfzal when you write this : 
var origin = readableJSONFromWeb["results"]
maybe try changing this to 
var origin = readableJSONFromWeb["results"] as! NSArray

Comment: @AkshanshThakur app is crashing by casting  readableJSONFromWeb["results"] as NSArray

Comment: I'm sorry, I cant think of anything.. it looked like an array, just make sure when casting, you used as! instead of as. I hope that sorts.

Comment: I do not understand its working fine when i read data from file, what could be the issue with web

Comment: yeah i used asI instead of as

Comment: I got it working now with                     origin = readableJSONFromWeb["results",0,"location","postcode"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscripting like this with SwiftyJSON:

```
var origin = readableJSONFromWeb["results","location"]
```

only works if the entire path is made of *dictionaries*.

But your `results` key holds an *array*, so you have to pass the index of the array item you want to get.

Example for getting the first item from the array:

```
var origin = readableJSONFromWeb["results",0,"location"]
```

Result:

```
{
  "city" : "sittard-geleen",
  "postcode" : 85004,
  "street" : "4774 pieterskerkhof",
  "state" : "flevoland"
}
```

Comment: I got it working but did not knew this dict and array thing now i understands it. Thanks for your time @EricD